# Animate BFS Traversal using JPanel

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to animate the BFS traversal using a JPanel.

Console output shows the algorithm is working...

```
BFS: 
A B C D E F
```

For the given graph:

[image]

**BFS snippet:**

```
public void bfs() {

    Queue q = new LinkedList();
    q.add(rootNode);
    rootNode.visited(true);
    rootNode.setColor(Color.cyan);
    printNode(rootNode);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {

        Nodes n = (Nodes)q.remove();
        Nodes child = null;
        //put all unvisited children in the queue
        while ((child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n)) != null)
        {
            //
            child.visited(true);
            //visited color = cyan
            child.setColor(Color.cyan);
            printNode(child);
            q.add(child);

        }
    }
}
```

So, I figured the best way to animate it on a JPanel was by adding a timer which calls `bfs()` every 1 second... And change the `while` loops to `if` statements... so when it's called it will iterate once per node and mark it as visited.

```
public void bfs() {

    Queue q = new LinkedList();
    q.add(rootNode);
    rootNode.visited(true);
    rootNode.setColor(Color.cyan);
    printNode(rootNode);
    if (!q.isEmpty()) {

        Nodes n = (Nodes)q.remove();
        Nodes child = null;
        //put all unvisited children in the queue
        if ((child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n)) != null)
        {
            //
            child.visited(true);
            //visited color = cyan
            child.setColor(Color.cyan);
            printNode(child);
            q.add(child);

        }
    }
    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        cancelTimer = true;
    }
}
```

It's getting through nodes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, but now won't visit children of `B`: `E` and `F`...

[image]

I'm using a paintComponent with `repaint()` to change the nodes color upon visitation...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.setColor(rootNode.getColor());
    g.fillRect(rootNode.getX(), rootNode.getY(), rootNode.getWidth(), rootNode.getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(rootNode.getValue(), rootNode.getX()+9, rootNode.getY()+16);
    paintComponent(g, rootNode);    
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Nodes parentNode) {  
    //keep generating new nodePrintList to load with new Children
    ArrayList<Nodes> nodePrintList = new ArrayList<Nodes>();    

    //base case: end of nodeList
    if (nodeList.indexOf(parentNode)==nodeList.size()-1) {
        System.out.println("\nend");
    }
    else {  
    //traverse nodeList recursively 
        nodePrintList = getChildren(parentNode);    
        //loop through and print all children of node n
        //System.out.println();
        int x = parentNode.getX()-50;

        for (Nodes child : nodePrintList) {             
            g.setColor(child.getColor());
            child.setX(x);
            child.setY(parentNode.getY()+50);
            g.fillRect(child.getX(), child.getY(), child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());        
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(child.getValue(), child.getX()+9, child.getY()+16);
            x+=50;
            //System.out.print("PARENT: " + parentNode.getValue() + " | x,y: " + parentNode.getX() + ", " + parentNode.getY() + "...\n CHILD: " + child.getValue() + " | x,y: " + child.getX() + ", " + child.getY());  
            paintComponent(g, child);
            g.drawLine(parentNode.getX()+10, parentNode.getY()+23, child.getX()+10, child.getY());
        }           
    }repaint();

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please don't prefix questions with tags, the tags have a purpose. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revise your algorithm.  Each time you call `bfs()`, you are starting the search over at the root node, 'A'.

The algorithm iteratively marks 'B', 'C', and then 'D' as visited children of 'A', and then... that's it.  'A' has no unvisited children so `bfs()` doesn't do anything anymore;  There is no `while` loop from which the children of 'B' can be explored

You need to set up some form of persistent state so that the bfs() method will in fact go through all of the nodes, 1 by 1.  [Iterative Deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) might be a good place to start, since DFS can be made iterative with a simple stack.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, torque. Is there some way to use the timer to delay how quickly the while loop is run (aka, delay how quickly the nodes are painted teal)? That was I can just call the `bfs()` method once and let the timer do the job of delaying.

Comment: Why not just `Thread.sleep(1000)` after every call to paint a node teal?